# Compressing text file containing new line characters in Node.js results in corrupt gzip file

Tags: node.js, gzip, newline

Following the trivial code example below copied directly from https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib, will result in a corrupt gzip file if the input text file contains newline characters!

When unzipping the resulting file from the terminal using `unzip input.txt.gz` I get the following error (unzipping by double clicking the file in Finder will yeild a similar error):

> End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
>     a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
>     latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
>     the last disk(s) of this archive.

What am I missing? Surly you must be able to compress text files that contain newline characters?!

I use Mac OS 10.15.3 with node 12.14.1.

input.txt (tried to insert a trailing newline character, but it does not make a differance):

```
hello
world
```

Node.js code:

```
const { createGzip } = require('zlib');
const { pipeline } = require('stream');
const {
  createReadStream,
  createWriteStream
} = require('fs');

const gzip = createGzip();
const source = createReadStream('input.txt');
const destination = createWriteStream('input.txt.gz');

pipeline(source, gzip, destination, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', err);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gzip is not ZIP. Gzip only compresses a single stream; ZIP is an archive format that packs multiple files into one archive, and each file may be compressed with a different method or not at all, too.

To decompress something you've compressed with Gzip, use the `gunzip` tool.